# jquery mobile white space at the bottom

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, space

i am developing a mobile application with jquery mobile, when i test on a desktop it comes out properly.
but when i test on a mobile device its shows a blank white space at the bottom, and  i have no footer, so i am surpised, also whenever i use my menu icon to triger my panel a second time it affects the look of my panel,

screen shot:
[image]

I use a tekno mobile android android 4.2.2

This is the [url](http://geneithpharm.com/app/about.php) to my app.

I would really appreciate any help on this as it is breaking my app

Comment: you can inspect element to see whats going on.

Comment: pls thats what i really need help on, i am unable to figure it out, please help

Comment: You have some problems with the height of the main panel. Try to find out where the dark box come from by changing the other colors, so you will better see it in the inspector.

Comment: wow so confused on this one

Comment: iv done that, it likes it comes form behind, but how do i eliminate this

Answer (score 0):

i finally found away around, this helped

```
data-position="fixed" for my header
```

Thanks every one, i do appreciate ur contributions.